# How to get maximum number of child processes inside a Docker container?

Tags: linux, docker

I'm trying to run the following program inside a Docker container, which is started with `--privileged`:

```
root@1df00aaf673d:~# cat > sysconf_test.c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long n = sysconf(_SC_CHILD_MAX);
    printf("%ld %d\n", n, errno);
    return 0;
}
root@1df00aaf673d:~# gcc sysconf_test.c ; ./a.out
-1 0
```

Going by [the `sysconf` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html), "If name corresponds to a maximum or minimum limit, and that limit is indeterminate, -1 is returned and errno is not changed." Is there a way to make it determinate, perhaps by passing an option to the `docker run` command?

Comment: What happens when you run the code on host?

Comment: It gives me the right value for the host; something like `15934 0` (I'll update later with the exact value.) Looks like there's something weird going on with the ulimits in the Docker container. I realize now that the question needs more information, so please wait until I've researched it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer my own question: it appears that `sysconf` returns `-1L` for "unlimited", although the man page doesn't spell it out:

```
[root@llg00amn ~]# ulimit -u
120996
[root@llg00amn ~]# docker run -ti debian /bin/bash
root@5668a7acb957:/# ulimit -u
unlimited
```

After setting the `ulimit` to an actual number, the program runs fine and returns the right result.